# Conditional probability proof of $P(B|A)$

Tags: probability

I was asked in a exam.I couldn't solve the problem.And I am also confused in $[.]$. Is it box function or bracket?

> Consider events $A$ and $B$ such that $P(A)=p_1>0$ and $P(B)=p_2>0$ and $p_1+p_2>1$. Show that $P(B|A)\ge1-\left[\frac{1-p_2}{p_1}\right]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(B\mid A)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

$P(A\cap B)~{=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)\\ \geq p_1+p_2-1}$

You deduce that $P(B\mid A)~{\geq \dfrac{p_1+p_2-1}{p_1}\\=1-\dfrac{1-p_2}{p_1}}$

Comment: Why can we deduce $\ge$ when $P(A\cup B)$ is strictly greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a bracket, not the box function.

The proof just requires using the inequality $P(A\cap B)\ge P(A)+P(B)-1$, which follows from the fact that $P(A\cup B)\le1$.

Comment: thanks,but can you provide further steps.as I have also come to this.